# D3 and updating elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rxjs, frp

Let's say that I have a 2d array called `state` that looks like `[[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,2,1]]`. The members of this array are constantly updating. I have D3 successfully rendering each member of the array with the following code:

```
function view(state)
  const vis = d3.select('body')
                .selectAll('div')
                .data(state)
                .enter()
                  .append('div')
                  .attr('style', 'display: flex')
                  .selectAll('span')
                  .data((d,i) => d)
                  .enter()
                    .append('span')
                    .text(d => d)
  return vis
}
```

Now consider that this `view` function is called every time my `state` changes. How can I get D3 to re-render only the elements that have changed since the previous render? Currently, the page renders initially but D3 never re-renders any of the elements, despite the `view` function being called at each state change.

If you'd like to see the full source, I posted it [here](https://gist.github.com/bstro/10171ff420739616dbf1)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah to handle such a case you need to make use of `enter` *which you are doing* to create new elements and `exit` to remove any element not in the current array.

I ll recommend you to do it this way:

```
function view(state)
  var visData = d3.select('body')
                .selectAll('div')
                .data(state, function(d){/*uniquely identify each element in array*/return d;});

  const vis =  visData.enter()
                  .append('div')
                  .attr('style', 'display: flex')
                  .selectAll('span')
                  .data((d,i) => d)
                  .enter()
                    .append('span')
                    .text(d => d);
  //remove the unnecessary data divs.
  visData.exit().remove();

  return vis
}
```

Further on enter exit [read](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.ko3er1b2g)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 cases when you want to render your data: when you add new view elements (divs, spans and text), and when you update your data (text). In your code you've done the first step only. You should do the second one.

d3.js provides selections for both cases. When you write

```
var div = d3.select('body').selectAll('div');
```

you get what already exists on your view. But if you add `.enter()`, i.e.

```
var div = d3.select('body').selectAll('div').enter();
```

it is already the second case. You are getting what doesn't exist yet, and should be created.

Since your data are changing, you should divide your code into two parts: view creation, view updating.

Here is [a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/DmitryMyadzelets/Lr55kjgt/) how it could be done for you code. The example can be improved, and the create/update code sections can be separated and put to corresponding functions, [see there](https://jsfiddle.net/DmitryMyadzelets/cfzh10b4/).

Anyway, I encourage you to read the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) for d3.js.